# Cannot bind to the property or column on the DataSource. vb.net

Tags: vb.net, gridview, data-binding, vb.net-2010

I have error Cannot bind to the property or column please solution. For notes I use studio visuals 2010. Is there the best solution or recommendation?.

thanks
jack

```
Dim Path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
Dim cn As String = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Path & "; Extended Properties=dBase IV"
    Dim WithEvents bmb As BindingManagerBase
    Dim dsTest As New DataSet
Private Sub CreateDataSetfillgridview()
 Try
            Dim query As String = "select EMPLOYEEN,HIREDATE FROM TRIAL"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(CStr(query), con)
                    Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                         da.Fill(dt)
                        dsTest.Tables.Add(dt)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
            'Bind controls 
            DataGrid1.DataSource = dsTest
'if I comment the code below then a dataset appears as screenshot below
            Me.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dsTest, "EMPLOYEEN")
            Dim MyBinding As New Binding("Value", dsTest, "HIREDATE")
            AddHandler MyBinding.Format, AddressOf dtFormatter
            AddHandler MyBinding.Parse, AddressOf dtParser
            DateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add(MyBinding)

            'Force a Refresh of bound controls
            bmb = Me.BindingContext(dsTest, "TRIAL")
            bmb.Position = bmb.Count
            bmb.Position = 0
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
```

[image: Cannot bind to the property or column]
[image: Value cannot be null Parameter name dataTable]
[image: VIEW DATA]
[image: datagrid not load row]
[image: datagrid load row when clicked]
[image: Cannot bind to the property or column EMPLOYEEN on the DataSource.]

Comment: Of course it can't bind. When did you populate `dsTest.Tables("TRIAL")`? Nowhere that you've shown us.

Comment: @user18387401 , so the solution

Comment: I pointed out that you're not populating the `DataTable` that you're binding. The solution is obvious. Maybe take a look at your code and see why you're not doing what you obviously intended to do.

Comment: `da.Fill(dt)` -> `da.Fill(ds.Tables("TRIAL"))`

Comment: Visual Studio can make all your life so much easier in this regard.. Add a new DataSet type of file, open server explorer, add a connection to your access db, expand it and drag the nodes rom server explorer into the dataset, then go to a form and open the data sources window and drag the dataset nodes onto the form. VS will, with thes two drag ops, write all that code you wrote there, and more, and it'll work first time

Comment: @CaiusJard ,
I used your code, there is an error "Value cannot be null Parameter name dataTable". I've updated in your post code and I'm using database dbf

Comment: Did you call `dsTest.Tables.Add("TRIAL")` when you made your dataset?

Comment: Also, turn on Option Strict/Explicit. You have left `Me.DataGrid1.DataSource = dt` loitering in your code but `dt` isn't defined anywhere, so the fact that it runs at all indicates to me that your VB is probably still running in "sling any old crap in and wait for the bugs at runtime" mode

Comment: @CaiusJard , if I comment the code below then a dataset appears like the screenshot below that I marked in my code then the dataset appears in the gridview. Why gridview does not load the line automatically and if I uncomment the code then still error "Cannot bind to the property or column EMPLOYEEN on the DataSource."

Comment: You can't set a control's DataSource to be a DataSet unless you also set the DataMember property. A dataset is a collection of tables, the DataMember specifies which table. Either set the DataSource to a DataTable, or set the DataSource to be a DataSet and set the DataMember to the name of a table within the set

Comment: doesn't this strike you as being incredibly hard work? Make a new project (so you don't disturb any existing code), connect the server explorer to your database file, put a new DataSet type of file, drag tables from the server explorer into the dataset, then open the Data Sources window and drag nodes from the dataset onto the form. All this code will be written for you

Comment: @CaiusJard , thank you for your guidance so I managed to do i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all thanks to the guide from @CaiusJard

```
Dim Path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
Dim cn As String = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Path & "; Extended Properties=dBase IV"
    Dim WithEvents bmb As BindingManagerBase
    Dim dsTest As New DataSet
Private Sub CreateDataSetfillgridview()
 Try
            Dim query As String = "select EMPLOYEEN,HIREDATE FROM TRIAL"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(CStr(query), con)
                    Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("TRIAL")
                         da.Fill(dt)
                        dsTest.Tables.Add(dt)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
            'Bind controls 
          DataGrid1.DataSource = dsTest.Tables("TRIAL")
            Me.TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dsTest, "TRIAL.EMPLOYEEN")
            Dim MyBinding As New Binding("Value", dsTest, "TRIAL.HIREDATE")
            AddHandler MyBinding.Format, AddressOf dtFormatter
            AddHandler MyBinding.Parse, AddressOf dtParser
            DateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add(MyBinding)

            'Force a Refresh of bound controls
            bmb = Me.BindingContext(dsTest, "TRIAL")
            bmb.Position = bmb.Count
            bmb.Position = 0
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
```